# Solving a distribution differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

The exercise is to solve

$$x u'(x) = \delta(x).$$

By using the definitions

$$\begin{cases}(u'|\varphi) = (-u|\varphi') \\ (fu|\varphi) = (u|f\varphi) \end{cases}$$

we get to solve

$$(-u|\varphi + x\varphi') = \varphi(0).$$

How do one proceed? Obviously we can see that $(-\delta|\varphi)$ is a solution, but what about other distributions?

Comment: Is $(\,\cdot\,|\,\cdot\,)$ meant to be an inner product of functions?

Comment: @Christoph $(u|\varphi)$ is a notation for the action $u[\varphi] = u(\varphi)$ of some test function $\varphi$ under the distribution $u$.

Comment: Do you know the general solutions to $xv(x) = \delta(x)$?

Comment: @md2perpe I'd guess some linear combination of Dirac deltas and a constant term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $v=u'$ we get the equation $xv=\delta$. The general solution to this is $v=-\delta'+a\delta,$ where $a$ is a constant. To get the general solution to $xu' = \delta$ we therefore need to solve $u' = -\delta'+a\delta,$ which is solved by $u=-\delta+aH+b,$ where also $b$ is a constant.

Thus, the general solution to $xu'=\delta$ is $u=-\delta+aH+b,$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

The solutions $v=-\delta'+a\delta$ to $xv=\delta$ can be seen as a particular solution $v=-\delta'$ and solutions to the homogeneous equation $xv=0$ which are $v=c\delta.$

Comment: Note there's a derivate acting on u.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver. I know. I had missed it at one place. Except for this my solution was correct.

Comment: Could you add a concluding line about the total solution?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver. A concluding line has been added (the second paragraph). I also added "Setting $v=u'$ /.../".

Comment: @md2perpe how did you find $v=-\delta'$ as a particular solution?

Comment: @ric.san That was just one choice. I could have taken $v=-\delta'+3\delta$ or $v=-\delta'-27389\delta$ as a particular solution. It was just most natural to choose $v=-\delta'.$

Comment: Ok, but.. it's not that obvious to "guess" these solutions. Isn't there a way to derive them (using for instance the previous definitions)?

Comment: @ric.san When finding the general solution in the first paragraph, I used the identity $x\delta'=-\delta$ and a theorem saying that the only solutions to $xu=0$ are $u=C\delta,$ where $C$ is a constant. This is similar to how you normally do it for ordinary functions.

Comment: Ok, but suppose I don't know that $x\delta'=-\delta$... is there a procedure to find $v=-\delta'$ as a particular solution of $xv=\delta$?

Comment: @ric.san I don't know of any easy procedure.