# A distribution differential equation

Tags: distribution-theory, greens-function

*Problem*. Find a particular solution $v \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$xv=\delta$$
knowing just the basic [operations on distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Operations_on_distributions).

Comment: Background: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087600/solving-a-distribution-differential-equation/3091334?noredirect=1#comment9054807_3091334

Comment: You have been around almost a year, so please add a bit of context to the Question.  Where did you see this problem?  What makes it important or challenging?  What progress did you make by applying the "basic operations on distributions"?  Please edit your Question's body to comply with Math.SE standards for content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we want to solve the distributional equation $xv=u,$ where $u$ is a given distribution and $v$ is unknown, the one we want to find. Then
$$
\langle u, \phi \rangle
= \langle xv, \phi \rangle
= \langle v, x\phi \rangle.
$$
Thus, if $\psi \in C^\infty_c$ has the form $\psi=x\phi$ for some $\phi\in C^\infty_c$ then we can just set $\langle v, \psi \rangle = \langle u, \phi \rangle.$ But what if $\psi$ does not have that form?

Take $\rho\in C^\infty_c$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and set $\tilde\psi = \psi - \psi(0) \rho.$ Then $\tilde\psi(0) = 0$ and $\tilde\psi=x\phi$ for some $\phi\in C^\infty_c.$ We conclude that
$$
\langle v, \psi \rangle
= \langle v, \tilde\psi + \psi(0)\rho \rangle
= \langle v, \tilde\psi \rangle + \psi(0) \langle v, \rho \rangle
= \langle u, \phi \rangle + C \langle \delta, \psi \rangle,
$$
where $C=\langle v, \rho \rangle$ is a constant w.r.t. $\psi.$

Note now that a Maclaurin expansion of $\tilde\psi$ gives $\psi(x) = \psi(0)+\psi'(0) x + O(x^2)$ so $\tilde\psi(x)=\psi'(0)x + O(x^2)=x\left(\psi'(0)+O(x)\right)$ giving $\phi=\psi'(0)+O(x).$ For $u=\delta$ we therefore get
$$
\langle u, \phi \rangle 
= \phi'(0) 
= \langle \delta, \phi' \rangle
= -\langle \delta', \phi \rangle,
$$
so $v=-\delta' + C\delta.$